# Laravel working on local but not on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I've been developing in Laravel 10 in my local, and seeing the web using `php artisan serve` then I uploaded all those files to a webserver, updated .env file with the new DB and url data, and tried a couple of times and work ok!! But after some hours, it stoped working. I can access the root folder and see the Laravel main screen, but if I want to access some controller it says "Target class  does not exists".

I guess it worked on local, and then on the server the firsts times, until some cache refreshed and then it didn't work anymore.

I accessed the webserver through ssh and run:

```
composer update
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev as 
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```

But nothing seems to work. Any idea what could be happening?

EDIT: If I add add the namespace in the route like this

```
Route::get('/landing', 'App\Http\Controllers\LandingController@index');
```

instead of this:

```
Route::get('/landing', 'LandingController@index');
```

it works fine! But I need to know WHY on local it works without adding the namespace and in the webserver it doesn't!

EDIT 2: I move this to it's own subdomain, so it isn't in a subfolder anymore, and it still happens.

Comment: share the error statement or screenshot.

Comment: @SachinKumar shared!

Comment: ok I guess you need to call `composer dump-autoload` command and it will update the autoload file.

Comment: what is the filename for the file this class is in?

Comment: composer dump-autoload didn't help @SachinKumar This works on local env. I added more info to the post.

Comment: the filename is LandingCrontroller @lagbox I added more info to the post

Comment: are any other routes are working @DavidTG

Comment: php artisan optimize, it needs to be cached after clear, try this on local and server, also make sure you have namespace your route file.

Comment: @AliRaza I updated the original post with extra info. If I add the namespace to the route, it works in webserver. But why I can't do it without it like in localhost?

Comment: Have you imported the LandingController class in routes ? Try this 
Route::get('/landing', [LandingControlle::class,  'index']); .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of Laravel are not supporting this syntax in routes:

```
Route::get('/landing', 'LandingController@index');
```

But this one

```
Route::get('/landing', [LandingController::class, 'index']);
```

Even if I don't know why it worked on localhost and not on webserver, as the documentations says that, I could guess is a bug or an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

from the error uploaded , it seems like the LandingController file does not exist or is not well named (check namespaces)  and the controller exist.

run a

```
php artisan route:list
```

to confirm you are not getting the same error.
also you might want to check your route service provider file to be sure its  is set to 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'

Comment: if I do that on the webserver I get  Class "LandingController" does not exist. If I do it on local, with the same codebase, I get  the routes lists. Why is different? Also, I don't get the namespace advice.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is permission , Cd to the file and run ls -al to see the permission

Comment: by doing that I get the same permissions as the file Controller.php and those are -rw-r--r--

Comment: Not sure about the user running your webserver  (NGinx/)Apache)
but you want to be sure they have the right permission; also you should confirm if any other controller is working on your project; that way, you can isolate the problem. as a general solution,  try and change the permission on the project folder like this 
 nginx => webserver user 
`sudo chown -R nginx:nginx ProjectFolder/  `
`sudo find  ProjectFolder/  -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;   `
`sudo find   ProjectFolder/  -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; `
`sudo chmod -R 777  storage `
`sudo chmod -R 777  bootstrap/cache/`

Comment: I updated the original post with extra info. If I add the namespace to the route, it works in webserver. But why I can't do it without it like in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you've got your namespace and class name in check for that LandingController. Make sure it's all spelt right and in the right directory. You know how PHP is picky about that case sensitivity stuff, so keep an eye out for that too.

You mentioned you did the composer song and dance with composer dump-autoload, which is a good move. That helps with autoloading, so props for that. also, don't forget to give those cache gremlins the boot! Run

> `php artisan route:clear`,

> `php artisan view:clear`

> `php artisan cache:clear`

and one more think the permissions can be real finicky, so make sure your files and folders are playing nice with the web server. No one likes a party crasher, especially when it's a permission issue.

Comment: I added some info in the original post that's related with namespaces...

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have one main application(https://www.rucalaf.com/) and you deploy your Laravel application inside a subdirectory(rucacrm) and access through URL segment i.e https://www.rucalaf.com/rucacrm/public.

When you were doing local development, at that time you don't have such a folders segment environment, you were just using `localhost:8000`.

The solution could be to change the line in the ".htaccess" file in the root folder from  `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]`

However, this could be weird to deploy in a subfolder. You have to update the .htaccess redirection rules, assets serving, and so on. As your main application could have its own htaccess rules and so on.

You can read from here - https://lucabecchetti.medium.com/configure-laravel-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-and-with-artisan-serve-at-the-same-time-654ba0c1fd0b

But I suggest creating a subdomain and deploying your Laravel application there.